# How to Intercept, skip method execution and continue with the rest of the stack

Tags: c#, aop, interceptor

Is there a way to intercept a method call, look for a condition and skip the execution? The method doesn't return anything and I would like to consider it as successfully completed and continue the execution with the rest of the stack.

```
public IMessageSink NextSink {
    get { return m_next; }
}

public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) {
    if (//some condition is met) {
        // should skip the method execution
    } else {
        IMessage returnMethod = m_next.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
        return returnMethod;
    }
}
```

Comment: just return nothing `return;`

Comment: FYI if your condition happens to be checking if `m_next == null`, as seems likely, then you do do this in one line in C# 6:  `return m_next?.SyncProcessMessage(msg);`

Answer (score 1):

The [return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) statement terminates execution of the method. In this case you should use `return null` because `SyncProcessMessage()` have to return value of `IMessage`

```
public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) {
    if (//some condition is met) {
        return null;
    } else {
        IMessage returnMethod = m_next.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
        return returnMethod;
    }
}
```

or something like that:

```
public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) {
    IMessage returnMethod  = null;
    if (! //not some condition is met) {
        returnMethod = m_next.SyncProcessMessage(msg);            
    }
    return returnMethod;
}
```

Comment: return null is throwing an exception. exception: 
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: The method was called with a Message of an unexpected type.
Result StackTrace: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.CallProcessMessage(IMessageSink ms, IMessage reqMsg, ArrayWithSize proxySinks, Thread currentThread, Context currentContext, Boolean bSkippingContextChain)

Comment: @Kiran of course, you should to catch  it in please where you call the `SyncProcessMessage()`